# Publish generic file as ivy artifact

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I want to publish a generic file to our Artifactory as a ivy artifact, and I have tried using the "Generic-Artifactory Integration" option in the job configuration.

The deployment works, but the file is deployed as a straight up file in the Artifactory repository root, e.g.

```
<artifactory url>/artifactory/ivy-repo/my.file
```

How can I the plugin publish the artifact as an Ivy dependency instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Generic Artifactory Integration you should define deployment patterns (as described in the tool-tip in Jenkins:
[image]

Since there is no way for Artifactory to determine the org path for a file without metadata (ivy.xml or pom.xml), you have to provide it manually in the right-hand part of the pattern expression, e.g. `my.file=>my/org/*`

Comment: What if I would have an ivy.xml file with the required metadata? Would it be than possible to publish it under the deployment path as defined there?

Comment: If you have ivy.xml, just use the [Ant/Ivy integration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringIvyAntBuilds).